# Read /proc/pid/maps using read()

Tags: c, proc, system-calls

I want to extract the information from `/proc/pid/maps`, such as: the start address, the end address, and the permission.

However, for learning purpose, I want to use the low-level system call, such as: `open`, `read`, and `lseek`.

I am confused how to grep the information I need. There are some challenges I found:

1. How to read the whole file using `read()`?

Right now, I am using `while((n = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0)`, to read the file, but apparently it reads in multiple batch, increasing the `BUFSIZ` * 2, does not solve the problem.

2. I am trying to grep the start address, by, read the character one by one until I find the `-` separator, and then `lseek` to the first character in the line and use `read` to get the start address. It works fine for the first iteration, but it mess up for the second iteration of `while((n = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0)`.

What is the best way to extract the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, `read(fd, buf, BUFSIZ)` will read `BUFSIZ` bytes from `fd`
  (unless you’ve reached the last block,
  in which case it will read all the remaining bytes,
  the number of which will be returned in `n` and will be ≤`BUFSIZ`). 
  If you want to read all the data in one shot,
  you can do

  ```
  wc /proc/pid/maps
  ```

  to see how long it is 
  (and hence how big to make `BUFSIZ`). 
  But this would be counterproductive. 
  Reading an entire file into memory is rarely necessary or even useful,
  and you can’t go around changing the parameters in your programs
  every time you run them on a different input file. 
  If you want to learn how to write programs that read files,
  you’ll be much better off learning how to handle them a block at a time.
- The second part of your question doesn’t make much sense. 
  `grep`? 
  Are you writing a C program or a shell script (or both)?
- And reading data that you want, throwing it away,
  and going back and reading it again is a really bad habit to get into. 
  It’s ridiculous to read the start address up to the **`-`**,
  and then `lseek` backwards and read it again
  — ***especially*** if you’re talking about
  reading the entire file into memory. 
  If you’ve got the entire file in memory,
  why in the world would you want to read part of it again?
- I would recommend using `fgets`. 
  But, if you really prefer to use`read`, go ahead and do it. 
  You’ll need to look for newline (`\n`) characters
  and so identify the lines (`fgets` would do this for you)
  and then extract the desired information from the lines.
- You can certainly analyze the lines character-by-character if you want. 
  But I recommend `sscanf`. 
  Be sure to check the return value.

Comment: thanks. the objective of the second part it to get the start address, end address and the permission. So, if I already get each line, I still need to extract the information again.

Comment: Yes, after ```read```ing it, you have to go back and analyze / parse it. But you don’t want to ***read*** it a second time, which is what you seem to be talking about when you mention `lseek`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `/proc/pid/maps` is a line-based file, using `read()` to read the file is kind of cumbersome. I would suggest using `getline()` or `fscanf()` for this purpose.